# How do i Increment Char Type for a String in Java?

Tags: java, char

This works with a single character But i want to do it with a string, i have no idea how to do it.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        char c = 'A';
        c = c + 1;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Suppose the String is `"Hello World"` 
so the +1 increment would return `"Ifmmp xpsme"`

Comment: `toCharArray()` then loop

Comment: new String("Hello World");
      print Str.toCharArray(); But How do i increment +1 ?

Comment: @DeathRs - Hint : A loop would do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ***split the String*** into an ***array of chars*** and then ***add 1*** to each char:

```
public String sumToCharsAtString(String word) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if(c != ' ')
            c = (char) (c + 1);
        b.append(c);
    }
    return b.toString();
 }
```

You really dont need to use the ***StringBuffer***, but in order ***to save memory***, its a really good practice.

Comment: @DeathRs you are welcome! If this is the correct answer, i ask you to mark as correct, in order to avoid unanswered questions, if is not, please let us know why!

Comment: without if(c != ' ') the output is  Ifmmp!xpsme :D

Comment: @DeathRs Yes! Thats beacause ' ' is the has de 32decimal unicode and the '!' has the 33, so if you add 1 to ' ', then you get '!' which is the 33 decimal. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want only alphabetic characters to be incremented. If so, this should work as a general solution (assuming a non-null String):

```
public String incrementChars(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
            result.append((char) (c + 1));
        } else {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Note that if performance if especially important, you might be better off with an old-style for-loop that avoids the toCharArray call. But it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: Be careful with the letter Z. What do you want it to map into?

Comment: That is true, it will need to be accounted for, perhaps by writing "if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isAlphabetic((char) (c + 1)))" or similar - assuming that leaving z and Z as-is is acceptable.